# select menu refresh next select menu onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, onchange

I am trying to avoid a duplicate here, as did not see my issue resolved in any of the the other 'jQuery Select Menu' posts around SO.  Just looking to be nudged in the right direction.

I have a set of select boxes for searching through the results of cars by make and model.  Naturally, The first `<select>` is for the Make of a car. This `<select>` element is being populated on page load with PHP. Once a Make is selected a makeID is passed through AJAX to retrieve the set of models relative to the selected Make.

This is all working great, my problem is that when I make multiple selections to my Make list, it never refreshes the second `<select>` box, thus appending models to many different makes to the second `<select>` box.

How can I refresh the second `<select>` box to only show the current results relative to the selection of the first `<select>` box.

My HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label for="make">Make</label>
    <select name="make" id="make">
      <?php foreach ($usedMakes->MakeResult as $MakeResult) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $MakeResult->makeId; ?>"><?php echo $MakeResult->makeName; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="model">Model</label>
    <select name="model" id="model">
      <option value="" selected>Make a Selection</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button name="submit" id="submit">&nbsp;Submit&nbsp;</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

My JavaScript:

```
$("#make").change(function() {
  var makeId = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "process.inc.php?makeId=" + makeId,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      for(i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
        var modelId = data[i].ModelResult.modelId;
        var modelName = data[i].ModelResult.modelName;
        var response = "<option value=\"" + modelId + "\">" + modelName + "</option>";
        var appendedData = $(response).insertAfter($("#model option:first-child"));
        $("#model option:first-child").data(appendedData);
      };
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You have to remove all the option children elements in the select before adding more options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the options

```
$("#model option").remove();  //removes all
$("#model option:gt(0)").remove();  //leaves first item, removes the rest
```

You should only update the once you build the whole list, not in a for loop

```
  var list = "":
  for (i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
    var modelId = data[i].ModelResult.modelId;
    var modelName = data[i].ModelResult.modelName;
    list += "<option value=\"" + modelId + "\">" + modelName + "</option>";
  };
  var theSelect = $("#model");
  theSelect.find("option:gt(0)").remove();
  theSelect.append(list);
```

Comment: First off, thank you for the response.  I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'gt'`.  Any suggestions?  Simply removing the `.gt(0)` method seems to work just fine.  Is it a required element?

Comment: whoops, it should have been in the selector. Sorry about that. I changed the code.

Comment: it would have been slice, not gt with the way I had it written originally.

Answer (score 0):

Just empty it on every response and then append it

Try this instead..

```
$("#model").empty()
```

and then append the new values in the ajax request.

This will make sure only the models for the current selection will be shown..